# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)-lab-logo.png

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

[image: error screenshot]I'm creating a project with ionic 5 angular and firebase. As i ran 'ionic lab', it gives 404 error that lab-logo.png can't be found (404). Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix:
Go to
/your-project/node_modules/@ionic/lab/www/index.html


Update the inline CSS in the head as follows:

Change this (old):

```
   #logo {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
          background: url('lab-logo.png');
```

To this:

```
 #logo {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background: url('./assets/lab-logo.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :))